# How do you correlate SQL Database Audit spec's log column transaction_id with a LSN? from trans log or CDC capture table?

Tags: audit, extended-events, change-data-capture

How do you correlate SQL Database Audit log column "transaction_id" with a LSN either from the trans log or a CDC capture table?
I am trying to do this because cdc only captures the data changes, while SQL Audit captures the who, when and what made the change. I am trying to correlate the two.
thx
~j

Comment: What database are you working with? SQL Server? Oracle? Something else? That kind of correlation typically requires a custom solution to capture data changes in an application-specific audit trail, as transaction logs and CDC logs aren't intended to be permanent records. Those kind of change logs typically only last a few days (or even less) before being overwritten or deleted to make room for more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back.
It's SQL Server 2019. I am using a combination of CDC and SQL Audit. The CDC is to capture the table data changes (4 tables) and SQL audit is to capture the who, when, what, etc made the changes. (using dml DB Audit spec events on the same tables)
There are not a whole lot of data changes on any given day and I realize the capture data has a retention period, so this is getting archived.
But for reporting purposes, I am trying to correlate the transaction_id from the SQL audit event log with the archived LSNs from the CDC capture data.

Comment: I do know how to get the transaction table's transaction id from the start lsn in the CDC _CT table, but can I correlate this to the transaction_id column in the SQL Audit log?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've been able to find for this is probably by querying `sys.fn_dblog`, **though it isn't officially documented or supported by Microsoft**. There is a very thorough 3rd party blog post about [Inside the Transaction Log file using fn_dblog and fn_full_dblog](https://blog.coeo.com/inside-the-transaction-log-file) (note to future readers that this should be archived at archive.org as well). For your specific case, you'd want to do something like:

```sql
SELECT
       [Current LSN]
       ,[Transaction ID]
       ,[Xact ID]
       ,[Begin Time]
       ,[End Time]
       ,[Transaction Name]
       ,[Transaction SID]
       ,[Parent Transaction ID]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(null,null)
WHERE [Transaction ID] = '0000:00011043'
```

You might want to periodically gather this data rather than specifying specific transaction IDs using a SQL Agent job since I'm not sure how long this data is maintained. I suspect it might go away after checkpointing.

However, I think the best way to try and do what you're doing would be to work with timestamps instead. Assuming you have audit setup to capture the necessary data, find the timestamp of the LSN you're interested in using `sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time`. After finding that timestamp, find all audit records around that time and then review the SQL statements associated with those records to determine which record was responsible.

However, even that isn't perfectly ideal since Audit only captures the first 4000 characters of the statement. If you want to make certain you capture everything, you'd need to create a custom session like https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/309903/281936. However, note that whether you use the `sqlserver.sql_text` action or the optional `statement` column present on certain events like `sqlserver.sql_statement_completed`, collecting the whole SQL statement is VERY expensive so you should either be prepared for significant impact on performance or use the `sqlserver.sql_text` action in conjunction with a carefully crafted predicate since actions are only evaluated after the predicate succeeds (predicates are also short circuited).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for getting back. This looks interesting. I'll post when I get some results.